# Can't type Korean In Lubuntu

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, korean

I understand that this is a question asked alot, but I have tried every solution, and I am still unable to type Korean

So, I have a Samsung Netbook, bought in US, so a US keyboard, but I am a Korean and I know Korean so I don't need a korean keyboard. I just want it to type. I installed lubuntu, and these are the things I have done.

- I went to language support, got Korean, went to Keyboard input Methods, and added Korean-Korean(101/104 key compatible) with iBus, but when I typed Ctrl + Space, the symbol at the bottom left of the taskbar, goes from US to KR but even when in KR English types, not Korean...
- I tried getting im-switch? and imhangul, but didn't work
- I tried with the LXkeymap, but that just did the same thing

Basicallly, my problem is that even with Korean Installed, and setup in the input method, When I type, English comes out instead of Korean..

Does anyone know another alternative method I can try? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you installed Korean, the *ibus-hangul* package ought to have been installed. If not, install it:

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-hangul
```

Next time you log in, run `ibus-setup` from a terminal window and select the input method *Korean - Hangul*.

Comment: oh my god.. thank you. I had installed ibus-hangul through the synaptic package installer, but hangul wasn't an option in the input method for some reason... after typing the two commands, it showed up.. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You may need to restart X or reboot after setting up ibus etc.

Depending on the program you are writing in, there may be an entry in the context menu on right mouse click in the text area or field you write to, where input method can be changed.